# How to build an array by using another one as a module?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array of numbers `Aij`. I want to create a new 2D array `Bij` by using the equation:

```
Bij = minB + (Aij / maxA) * (maxB - minB)
```

where `minB` and `maxB` are numbers that I have set them randomly for instance it could have been `minB = 20` and `maxB = 150` or `minB = 10` and `maxB = 250` or whatever. So let's say that `A` array is:

```
def f1(x1, y1):
    return x1 + y1

x1 = np.arange(10)
y1 = np.arange(10)
X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)
A = f1(X1, Y1)
maxA = max(A)
```

I try to build B:

```
maxB = input('Enter maxB:')
minB = input('Enter minB:')
B = np.empty((10, 10))
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        B[i, j] = minB + ((X1, Y1) / maxA) * (maxB-minB)
print(B)
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Seem you have issue when get maxA and input values. You can try:

```py
    import numpy as np

    def f1(x1, y1):
        return x1 + y1
    
    x1 = np.arange(10)
    y1 = np.arange(10)
    X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)
    A = f1(X1, Y1)
    maxA = max([max(a) for a in A])
    
    maxB = int(input('Enter maxB:'))
    minB = int(input('Enter minB:'))
    B = np.empty((10, 10))
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            B[i, j] = minB + (A[i, j] / maxA) * (maxB-minB)
    print(B)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over all the array:

```
def f1(x1, y1):
    return x1 + y1

x1 = np.arange(10)
y1 = np.arange(10)
X1, Y1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1)
A = f1(X1, Y1)
maxA = np.max(A)

maxB = float(input('Enter maxB:'))
minB = float(input('Enter maxB:'))
B = minB + (A / maxA) * (maxB-minB)
```